# from package import * - does the calling module have access to the namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When we use `from package import *` nothing really gets imported except if either of the following is true:

1. the `__init__` file of the pakcage had defined an `__all__` variable with list of modules to be imported.
2. The `__init__` file of package has code like `import module1` or `from package import module1`

I just want to get a confirmation that in both cases, only the specified modules run and that they are loaded in the package's `__init__` files namespace and not in the calling file's namespace (unlike if we had used `import module` or `import package` in which case we get reference to that module/package namespace)

Comment: `from package import *` This is called a star or wild import, and it isn’t so straightforward. This is also the reason why using it is generally discouraged.

Comment: Your second part about namespaces is confused—a module is not loaded “in” any namespace except its own (that contains its functions and classes).  The name of a module is bound in its package (if any) and sometimes (depending on `from` usage) in its importer.